# Know in what context DLL is running

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I want to know if the DLL is being used in web or desktop context. One way is to check if `HttpContext` is null or not. But I want to know if there is other better way to do it.

Comment: While there may be more ways, I don't think there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We went through the very same thing, as we have a .DLL that runs in both a Windows and a Web app and you've already nailed the way to determine which is which.

```
public bool IsWebApp()
{
    return (HttpContext.Current != null);
}
```

Then within your application, you just query:

```
if ( this.IsWebApp() )
{
    //do webby stuff...
}
```

Comment: This is not 100% reliable, because there are cases, when HttpContext.Current returns null in web application. For example in Application_Start method in global.asax or when called on new thread.