# Detect if request comes from "web site project" or "console project"

Tags: c#, web, console-application

I want to know what is the best way to detect from where a request has been sent (function calls)

The meaning: my project goes like this:

- Engine
- Web project (uses the engine)
- Test Project-console project (uses the engine)

Now I want that some code will not be executed in the function when I am running the Test project.

I know that I can send a boolean parameter to detect this but I want to know if there is any why to detect if the request comes from web project or not...

Thanks!!

Orel.

Comment: This link seems to be the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394740/know-in-what-context-dll-is-running

Answer (score 3):

If the code being called should behave differently based on whether the call comes from the web project or the console project, the code shouldn't be in a shared library. It really belongs in the respective project.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that `HttpContext.Current` is not null.  @JustinNiessner's advice is still applicable, however.

Comment: This will work in most cases, but it will return incorrect result, if called from Application_Start method in global.asax or from new thread (and probably in few other cases too).

Answer (score 2):

Compile your test project with TESTPROJECT symbol set and web project without this symbol. Then because of [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664622%28VS.71%29.aspx), SetIsFromTest() method will be executed only if your code was called from test project (and therefore field IsFromTest will be set to true).

```
static class Class1
{
    static bool IsFromTest = false;

    static Class1()
    {
        SetIsFromTest();
    }

    [Conditional("TESTPROJECT")]
    public static void SetIsFromTest()
    {
        IsFromTest = true;
    }
```

}

Another option is to test name of calling assembly from your shared library.

```
if(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName == "...")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [StackFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx) object to access stack trace and see what was the previous method calling yours. By using the method you could easily find the corresponding project. From older so [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310145/get-calling-function-name-from-called-function-in-c-sharp):

```
StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
int caller = 1;
StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(caller);
MethodBase callerMethod = frame.GetMethod();
```

Though I should warn you that's the thing you should use only for fun/when debugging.